# mouse select and filter in another tab Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a macro where I can use mouse to select a name in tab "Capacity", and by pressing hot key Ctrl+Shift+Z, macro will activate and search this name in tab "Allocation" in a name filter

I am stucked with how to use macro to copy what I selected and paste this to the filter criteria

I have tried with this

```
   Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    ' Resource allocaiton breakdown
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Z
    '
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Allocation").Select
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$9:$FL$529").AutoFilter Field:=6
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$9:$FL$529").AutoFilter Field:=1
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$9:$FL$529").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Target.Value"

End Sub
```

but it's not working,
I am fairly new to VBA
please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should [avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).
2. You cannot "copy" a cell value into a filter criteria instead you set the criteria to that value by using the cell value as `Criteria1`

So something like this should work:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FilterForSelectedValue()
    Dim SelectedFilter As Range
    Set SelectedFilter = Selection

    Worksheets("Allocation").Range("$A$9:$FL$529").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=SelectedFilter.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for replying PEH, but the name is selected from another tab "capacity", and filter is in "Allocation", would this still work?

Comment: @Elgatoo did you even try it? As you can see it filters a range in `Worksheets("Allocation")`. And it uses `Selection` on what ever sheet is selected at the moment you run the code.

Comment: Tried it, and added  Sheets("Allocation").Select
at the end of it, it seems working!!!
thank you so much,
and also if i want to assign hot keys to this, will it be the same?

Comment: @Elgatoo You can assign a hotkey to almost any macro you write. Why don't you try it before you ask?